# Binding database to my java web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, cloudbees

I've downloaded the Cloud Bees sdk and ran the following command:-
"bees app: bind -db graderegister -a ashishsfb/graderegister -as mydb"
It executed successfully but I don't know what changes I might have to do in my code or what I need to do next so as to connect to the database. My web application "Grade Register" was successfully running on my windows 7 pc with my data stored in mySQL. Please help as I'm very new with mySQL and Cloud Bees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Tomcat container that you use, binding the `graderegister` to your app `graderegister` with the alias name `mydb` will:

- Create a JNDI DataSource `java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb` that you can retrieve in your java code with:

  ```
  Context ctx = new InitialContext();
  DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb");
  ```
- Create system properties that you can use to manually create your database connection (`DATABASE_URL_MYDB`, `DATABASE_USERNAME_MYDB`and `DATABASE_PASSWORD_MYDB`) as described in [RUN@cloud » Binding services (resources) to applications](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Resource+Management).

If you manually create your database connection instead of using the JNDI DataSource, please remember that

- The value of the variable `DATABASE_URL_MYDB` should be prefixed by `jdbc:` in Java applications (this URL is language agnostic).

  `String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:" + System.getProperty("DATABASE_URL_MYDB");`
- Databases connections are automatically closed by the MySQL server, please use a validation query `SELECT 1`

**Additional Docs and Demos**

- http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Resource+Management
- https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/DatabaseGuide
- https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat-hibernate-clickstart